# pollSCM isn't working on my Jenkins job, am I doing this wrong?

Tags: docker, jenkins, github-actions

I'm new to Jenkins so I barely know what i'm doing. Started learning yesterday. I'm trying to host a webapp on a synology NAS in my network. I don't think I can use webhooks to for live updates because I don't have permission to open ports. So I want to regularly poll my repository for changes, and if there are changes, download them.

I'm also using docker, jenkins is running on a docker container inside the NAS. I have some github actions such that every time code is pushed to main, it builds and pushes the project into docker hub. I am trying to setup my jenkins job to query for changes on github, and if there are changes, stop the current container running on the NAS that's hosting the webapp, delete it, download the new docker image and run it.

Here's my github actions yml:

```
name: cicd

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/[myscriptname]
```

github actions works.

and heres my pipline script in jenkins:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('dockerhub-token')
        GITHUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('github-login')
        IMAGE_NAME = "[myusername]/[myscriptname]"
    }

    triggers {
        pollSCM('* * * * *') // This will poll SCM every minute
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: GITHUB_CREDENTIALS, url: 'https://github.com/myrepo.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build and Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS) {
                        def customImage = docker.build(IMAGE_NAME, "-f ./Dockerfile .")
                        customImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Redeploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Stop and remove the old container
                    def runningContainer = docker.ps("-q", "--filter", "name=myContainer")
                    if (runningContainer) {
                        docker.stop(runningContainer)
                        docker.rm(runningContainer)
                    }
                    
                    // Pull the latest image
                    docker.image(IMAGE_NAME).pull()
                    
                    // Run the new container
                    docker.run(
                        "--name myContainer -d -p 5173:5173",
                        IMAGE_NAME
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im using the pipeline script definition not pipeline script from SCM because I find it simpler to use.
all the other settings in the webUI for this job are blank.
For some reason it's not running at all unless I manually start the job. Even if I push a new change to the repo, the job doesn't seem to run.

I saw a post or 2 saying that I need to enable pollSCM in my pipeline or something?

The confusing thing is, that if I do a freestyle project and pollSCM that way, and use my github credentials like I just described using my PAT, it works. It's just when I use pollSCM in a pipeline script it doesn't trigger ever.